# Initialize 2D array in C using array of pointers

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, multidimensional-array

I have a static array that I want to use to initialize a dynamic array using pointers.

Right now I have this:

```
boardinit[BOARD_HEIGHT][BOARD_LENGTH] = {
        {-4, -2, -3, -5, -6, -3, -2, -4},
        {-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
        {4, 2, 3, 5, 6, 3, 2, 4},
    };
int main()
{
    int board[BOARD_HEIGHT][BOARD_LENGTH]; 
    initboard(board);

    for (int j = 0; j < BOARD_HEIGHT; j++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < BOARD_LENGTH; i++)
            printf("%d ", board[j][i]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}

void initboard(int (*pboard)[BOARD_HEIGHT]) 
{
    for(int i = 0;i<BOARD_HEIGHT;i++)
        pboard[i] = boardinit + i;

}
```

I want `board[BOARD_HEIGHT][BOARD_LENGTH]` to initialize as `boardinit[BOARD_HEIGHT][BOARD_LENGTH]` by passing board to `initboard()` using pointers, but can't seem to get it to go.

Comment: Not sure what _you_ mean by _dynamic_. Please _edit_ your question and add some clarification. At a guess ... Currently, you have `BOARD_HEIGHT/BOARD_LENGTH` as fixed constants either via `#define` or an `enum`. And, you want these values to be [global] `int` declarations (i.e. You can prompt the user for the width/height via (e.g.) `scanf`)???

Comment: I do not get what your question is. Do you observe any problems with the shown code? Would you like to describe them? Would you like to create a [mre] which demonstrates what you describe?

Comment: You have a two dimensional array, so you need nested loops that iterate the rows and columns. Or you could just use `memcpy(board, boardinit, sizeof(board))` in the `main` function.

Comment: it is a 8x8 array, and boardinit is a static array, it never changes. The array will always initialize as the listed values.

Since i am passing the 2d array as a pointer to an array of 8 ints, and in my current code i get a error of 

`expression must be a modifiable lvalue` for `pboard[i] = boardinit + i;`

Comment: If everything is fixed, you can simplify the `initboard` prototype: `void initboard(int pboard[BOARD_HEIGHT][BOARD_LENGTH]) { for (int irow = 0; irow < BOARD_HEIGHT; irow++) for (int icol = 0; icol < BOARD_LENGTH; icol++) pboard[irow][icol] = boardinit[irow][icol]; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To copy the contents `boardinit` to the value of `board`, just use this:

```c
memcpy(board, boardinit, sizeof(board));
```

If that does not work, try this:

```c
void initboard(int pboard[BOARD_HEIGHT][BOARD_LENGTH]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < BOARD_HEIGHT; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < BOARD_LENGTH; j++)
            pboard[i][j] = boardinit[i][j];
}
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your reply. Isn't the parameter of `initboard` a pointer to an array of BOARD_HEIGHT ints? Wouldn't that make indexing not work, forcing you to use pointer arithmetic since technically its not a 2D array?

Comment: @aaronb8 Why is it 'technically not a 2D array?'

Comment: Well, it's a pointer to a array of [8] ints. The parameter in your function you wrote is a copy of board from main, which is what i am trying to avoid.

Comment: @aaronb8 Arrays are passed by reference, pointer or not, so declaring the parameter as `int [BOARD_HEIGHT][BOARD_LENGTH]` does not make a copy of the board in `main`

Comment: Thanks. I'm new to C as you can tell.

Comment: @aaronb8 No problem, good luck on your code :)

Answer (score 0):

*"I have a static array that i want to use to initialize a dynamic array using pointers."*

The problem with arrays of pointers is that each call to `[m][c]alloc()` is not guaranteed (in fact is not likely) to provide a single contiguous block of memory.  i.e., this is a common approach that provide many little areas of memory:

```
int **array = malloc(sizeof(width * sizeof(int *));
{
     for(int i=0; i<width; i++)
     {
          array[i] = malloc(height*sizeof(int));
     }
}
```

Thus, the initializer would need to be broken into several memory block locations.

A simpler and more efficient way to do this is with a single dynamic memory allocation call, guaranteeing a single contiguous block of memory, then a single `memcpy()` is possible using the initializer into the pointer location returned from `[m][c]alloc()`.  The only problem then is how to access the memory area with array notation.  The example below illustrates how this can be done using `*(ptr + index)` notation...

```
//assuming your other code above
int main(void) 
{   
    int elements = BOARD_HEIGHT*BOARD_LENGTH;
    int *pArray = calloc(elements, sizeof(int));
    if(pArray)
    {
        memcpy(pArray, boardinit, sizeof boardinit);
        for(int i=0; i<BOARD_HEIGHT;i++)
             for(int j = 0;j<BOARD_LENGTH;j++)
                printf("%d\n", *(pArray + (i + j)));
        free(pArray);
    }
 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Using dynamic allocation (`malloc()` or `calloc()`) when stack allocations would be fine should be avoided

Comment: @BlockofDiamond - If you see anything that _suggests I am promoting_ the use of allocated memory here, that was not my intent.  The whole purpose of the first section of this answer was to point out  non-contiguous blocks of memory are not always optimal. The second part of my answer was just showing how to use OP's stated desire to use _"array of pointers"_ without non-contiguous memory.   Your answer already covered the array approach.  No need to cover it here.

Comment: Ok, I understand